# Xcode debugging not showing for- or while-loops

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, for-loop, while-loop

I pretty new to C++. I use Xcode. When i debug my code, it jumps/skip when it gets to some while- and for-loops.

My code (this works):

```
          //This code collects trigrams of a word and saves them in a vector.
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length()-1; i++){

                if (word.substr(i,3).length()>= 3){
                    trigrams.push_back(word.substr(i,3));
                    }
        }
                    sort(trigrams.begin(),trigrams.end());
```

My code ( that Xcode cannot debug and gives no error):

```
               //words is a vector class with arrays of words.
          //words[word.size()].size() is a vector with size 65753. which is correct.

                for(int i=0; i<words[word.size()].size();++i){

                if(words[word.size()].at(i).get_matches(trigrams)==trigrams.size()/2){
                    suggestions.push_back(word);
                }


        }
```

Is there a debug-configuration that I have missed? Is the loop to long? or is it just bad syntax combined with lack of knowledge?

At least I think I would reach the if-statements....but nope.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no special option to skip/enter loops in debugging. When this happens, your condition is probably false. E.g. for the second loop `i < words[word.size()].size()` is probably false, and so the loop is never entered. As to why the `words[word.size()].size()` is less than one, that's another question. Look to the place where it's populated.

You can also set a breakpoint right before the loop and see the values of `words[word.size()].size()` and so on.

Comment: I checked and it seems like it(words....size()) has a type-long value. But when it enters the for-loop it goes to zero for some reason.

Comment: @Oskar It's hard to pinpoint where exactly you're making the error. How is the `words` (vector?) populated? And what is it's type (I guess a map would make more sense)?